# How to obtain the orientation of a square in the real world from an image knowing the centroid position in the real world and the image projection

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, transform, shapes, projection

I'm trying to obtain the orientation of a square in the real world from an image. I know the projection of each vertex in the image and with this and a depth camera I can obtain the position of the centroid in the real world.

I need the orientation of the square (actually, the normal vector to the plane) and the depth camera has not enough resolution. The camera parameters are also known.

I've search and I've only found estimation algorithms too overkill for problems with much less information. But in this case, I have a lot of data of the shape, distance, camera, image, etc. but I am not being able to get it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the image is captured with an ordinary camera, and that your "square" is well approximated by an actual geometrical rectangle, with parallel opposite sides and orthogonal adjacent ones

If you only need the square's normal, and the camera is calibrated (in particular, the nonlinear lens distortion is removed from the image), then it can trivially be obtained from the vanishing points and the center. The algorithm is as follows:

1. Express the images of the four vertices `p_i, i=1..4`, in homogeneous coordinates: `p_i = (u_i, v_i, 1)`. The ordering of i is unimportant, but in the following I assume it's clockwise starting from any one vertex. Also, for convenience, where in the following I write, say, `i + n`, it's assumed that the addition is modulo 4, so that, e.g., `i + 1 = 1` when `i = 4`.
2. Compute the equations of the lines covering the square sides: `l_i = p_(i+1) X p_i`, where `X` represents the cross product.
3. Compute the equations of the diagonals: `d_13 = p_1 X p_3`, `d_24 = p_2 X p_4`.
4. Compute the center: `c = d_13 X d_24`.
5. Compute the vanishing points of the pairs of parallel sides: `v_13 = l_1 X l_3`, `v_24 = l_2 X l_4`. They represent the directions of the images of two lines which, in 3D, are orthogonal to each other.
6. Compute the images of the axes the 3D orthogonal coordinate frame rooted at the square center, and with two of the axes parallel to the square sides: `x = c X v_13`, `y = c X v_24`.
7. Lastly, the plane normal, in 3D camera coordinate frame, is their cross product: `z = x X y` .

Note that removing the distortion is important, because even a small amount of distortion can greatly affects the location of the vanishing points when the square sides are nearly parallel.

If you want to know why this works, the following excerpt from Hartley and Zisserman's "Multiple View Geometry in Computer Vision" should sufice:

[image]